# How to control of battery charging/discharging limits?

Tags: power-management, battery

I'm running HP 530 laptop and Ubuntu 10.04. My old battery had died some time ago, so I got a new one.

I'd like the possibility of being able to change the limits when the charger starts to charge the battery (e.g. <50%) and finished (e.g. >80%). It should sufficiently extend the battery life. 
See [How to Prolong Lithum-based Batteries.](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries)

I know that Lenovo users are lucky to be provided with a solution because of the [`tp_smapi` kernel module.](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi)

Is there a solution that helps?

Comment: it's hardware dependent thing, so it might be possible. I personally have no access to lenovo hardware, so i can't write any script for your specific case. Hardware-independent way would be to use notification for user to plug in/remove charger. For that, i do already have scripts. Let me know if you're interested in that

Comment: @Serg Could I have access to one of those scripts you mentioned, both for using it and also to learn from it? :)